# MonetDB OR Clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, monetdb

I have a very simple query that in the WHERE clause has something like "`employee_id = 60 and (manager in (-1) or -1 in (-1))`" and this will work fine in databases like SQL server, MySQL, Oracle, etc, bringing back the 1 employee_id record.  The -1's represent a prompt value, if nothing select for manager it defaults to -1 and so therefore no filter for manager is effective.

In MonetDB, it will just bring back all records; completely disregarding the employee_id filter.  I have NO idea why and it's driving me nuts.  The full query is below, if anyone has an idea please let me know.
Thanks,
Matt

```
select employee_id, manager_id
from employee
where employee_id = 60
and (manager_id in (-1) or -1 in (-1));
```

Comment: could you please provide a CREATE TABLE statement for `employee` so that others can reproduce this problem?  thanks!

Comment: Any table could be used actually; this issue is mainly around the concept/logic of the SQL.  But I'll include a create table & insert statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    employee_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    manager_id INTEGER NULL
);

INSERT INTO employee (employee_id,manager_id) values (50,70);
INSERT INTO employee (employee_id,manager_id) values (60,70);
INSERT INTO employee (employee_id,manager_id) values (70,null);
```

Comment: that does look weird.  two notes:  next time, submit it to bugs.monetdb.org yourself.  i have submitted this-- https://www.monetdb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3655   --  and in the future, *edit* your question rather than providing more detail in an answer.  :)  nonetheless, thanks for making this pretty easy to submit!

Answer (score 0):

you have found a bug.  this issue will be fixed in the next release of monetdb.  thanks for the reproducible example!

https://www.monetdb.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3655

Comment: No problem, Anthony, thank you for submitting.  And I apologize I failed to include the release of MonetDB we are using:  Jan2014-SP1